# SwiftUI using NavigationLink and NavigationView

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I am trying to use `NavigationView` and `NavigationLink` in my code below.
I heard that `NavigationLink` only works inside `NavigationView`.
However, whenever I embed my `ScrollView` into a `NavigationView`, the scrollView stop showing up and I get a blank space. I am not sure what is the reason behind it.

```
var body: some View {
        // I tried to embed the entire VStack into NaviationView. However, it ends up showing nothing as well
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(self.categoryName)
                    .font(.title)
                NavigationView {
                    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                        HStack(alignment: .top) {
                            ForEach (self.drummers) { drummer in
                                NavigationLink("Moreinfo", destination: drummerDetail(drummer: drummer))
                                aDrummer(drummer: drummer)
                                .frame(width: 300)
                                .padding(.trailing, 30)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
            }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If `aDrummer` is-a View (as I assume) then see below possible fix - ForEach content should be single view

```
ForEach (self.drummers) { drummer in
  VStack {
    NavigationLink("Moreinfo", destination: drummerDetail(drummer: drummer))
       aDrummer(drummer: drummer)
         .frame(width: 300)
         .padding(.trailing, 30)
  }
}
```